# Purpose of Spark Gap Collectors on Wimshurst Machine

Tags: electrostatics

A [wimshurst machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimshurst_machine) consists of neutralizer bars which directly contact opposing sectors.  However, the collector is described as having sharp points to facilitate corona discharge between the sector and the capacitor.

Is the reason why the collectors don't physically touch the sectors because that would mean they would touch the insulated disc as the machine is spinning, thereby grounding the collector? If so, could this be avoided by cutting out the space in between sectors from the disc?